# IOS: problem with double value to string

Tags: ios, xcode, double

I have this code

where I insert a double value in an array of arrays

```
double myDouble = [textField2.text doubleValue];
NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: textField1.text, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble], nil];
[appDelegate.extra addObject:temp];
```

after I do

```
NSString *cost = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", [[appDelegate.extra objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:1]];

[label1 setText:[[appDelegate.extra objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]];
[label2 setText:cost];
```

then if I write "1" in textField2 I have "0.00" in label2....why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *cost = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", [[appDelegate.extra objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
```